# Python datetime library not able to handle 01022018 i.e as in MMDDYYYY format when left most zero is truncated

Tags: python, datetime

I have an issue that I am encountering with one of the modules. Due to the requirement of data handlers, one of the modules has to use the `datetime` library and the `strptime` function. But the code behavior does not seem to be consistent, when the left most zero from a date series in format `MMDDYYYY` is truncated especially for Jan month. Below are some example,you can see the 2nd and third command are identical but the month is getting corrupted. Anyways around how to handle it?

```
>>> datetime.strptime('01082018',"%m%d%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 8, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.strptime('1082018',"%m%d%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 8, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.strptime('8082018',"%m%d%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 8, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.strptime('08082018',"%m%d%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 8, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Well, it's _not_ in `MMDDYYYY` format when a zero is truncated; it's in `MDDYYYY` format or `[M]MDDYYYY` format or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: You're using `%m`, which explicitly means "zero-padded decimal month". If you want to give it non-zero-padded decimal months, it's not going to work. Really, your second answer should be an error because `%d` is also explicitly zero-padded, but Python is reproducing the behavior of traditional Unix libc `strptime`.

Comment: Yes, it's true. after left truncation it becomes mddYYYY. I have written MMDDYYYY just to elaborate the positions of month and date so as not to confuse with DDMMYYYY

Comment: Well, Python can't guess what you _mean_, only what you _say_. And `%m%d%Y` says `MMDDYYYY`, not `MDDYYYY`.

Comment: What's more, if you choose to leave out leading zeroes, there are scenarios when it's ambiguous. What is 112018? What is 1112018? Find a way to fix your input.

Comment: @JimStewart: Well, `MDYYYY` is ambiguous, and so is `MMDYYYY or MDDYYYY`, but `MDDYYYY` isn't, and neither is `MMDYYYY` aren't, so if you really do want to use one of those to confuse human readers, you can parse it…

Comment: @abarnert : Thanks for your clarification , but can any other library handle this issue?

Comment: And, come to think of it, "`MDYYYY` as disambiguated the same way SysV Unix did it" isn't ambiguous either, it's just kind of useless.

Comment: @SatyaranjanRout Well, is your format really definitely `MDDYYYY` with the days never truncated? I _think_ `dateutil` can handle that; check the docs. Or of course you could parse it yourself. I've had to deal with a database where someone stored a bunch of `DDMMYYYY` dates as integers instead of strings, and it was easier to just divmod 1000 and 1000000 than to convert back to strings and parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split it in two multiple commands and append a zero (if need be)

```
>>> date_str = '01082018'
>>> if len(date_str)==7:
>>>     date_str = '0'+date_str
>>> datetime.strptime(date_str ,"%m%d%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 8, 0, 0)
```

AND

```
>>> date_str = '8082018'
>>> if len(date_str)==7:
>>>     date_str = '0'+date_str
>>> datetime.strptime(date_str ,"%m%d%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 8, 0, 0)
```